# Open C# exe in Winform Panel

Tags: c#

I just write a exe using C# code and I want to run the exe using SetParent in C# winform

```
Process proc = Process.Start(
        new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "Menu",
            Arguments = "/c echo hello user ^<!^> && pause",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        });
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel2.Handle);
```

Comment: You are trying to set the clock back to 1990, back when this was not a problem.  That program you are trying to run better be a 1990s kind of program.  Like Notepad, try it with that one first.  Very obvious mistakes are trying to put a minimized window in a panel and not waiting for the process to create its main window handle.  Calling Process.WaitForInputIdle() is a minimum requirement.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this (Menu filename doesn't have .exe extension)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

then in your function

```
 var proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Menu.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c echo hello user ^<!^> && pause",
 proc.Start();
 SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel2.Handle);
```

**update**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

then

```
 var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Menu.exe";

proc.Start();

IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
while ((ptr = proc.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero) ;
SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, trackerPanel.Handle);
MoveWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width - 90, this.Height, true);
```

refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: wich error did you get? is the process starting? try with empty arguments and let me know

Comment: But how I can set anchor and how to move window

Comment: please accept my naswer if it resolves your problem to avoid that this question remains unanswered

Comment: @user1301802 look at the link that I had left in the answer for references, there you can find how use that parameters